# TreeView's ScrollBar Not Accept VCL theme when mirroring

Tags: delphi, treeview, scrollbar, delphi-xe8, vcl-styles

`TTreeView's` ScrollBar does not accept VCL themes when mirroring the Treeview by this code:

```
procedure SetWinControlBiDi(Control: TWinControl);
const
 WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT = $00100000;
 WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL = $00400000;
var
 ExStyle: Longint;
begin
 ExStyle := GetWindowLong(Control.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
 SetWindowLong(Control.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyle or WS_EX_RTLREADING or WS_EX_RIGHT
   or WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT );
end;


procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   SetWinControlBiDi(TreeView1);
end;
```

Sample image:

[image]

what should I do?

pls help me...

Comment: Don't know what is exactly wrong but it works when you include @RRUZ's excellent [Vcl.Styles.Hooks](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils/wiki/VclStylesHook) unit

Comment: Additional note, if you set  `BiDiMode := bdRightToLeft;` on the form then the scrollbar is rendered correctly but the treeview RTL mode is not rendered correctly...

Comment: Thanks... @whosrdaddy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue in the `TScrollingStyleHook` style hook, you should report this to Embarcadero. Meanwhile you can use the [`Vcl Styles Utils`](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils) project to fix this.

Only you need follow the installation instructions and then add the `Vcl.Styles.Hooks` unit to your project.

[image]